# C++ How to capture int value inside conditional if statement and display it outside the if statement BEFORE it changes

Tags: c++, if-statement, get

```
    void Asteroids::OnScoreChanged(int score)
    {

       std::ostringstream msg_stream;
       std::ostringstream msg_stream2;
       std::ostringstream msg_stream3;


       msg_stream << "Score: " << score;
       msg_stream2 << "You scored: " << score;
       msg_stream3 << "diff score: " << score;

       // Get the score message as a string
       std::string score_msg1 = msg_stream.str();
       std::string score_msg2 = msg_stream2.str();
       std::string score_msg3 = msg_stream3.str();
       mScoreLabel->SetText(score_msg1);
       // need the value of score_msg2 below outside the if statement

       if (count == 1) {
          mTempLabel->SetText(score_msg2);
       }

      //and display it here when count = 2 but it changes when count increments

       if (count == 2) {
           //attempt to display score when count = 1
           mTempLabel2->SetText(score_msg2);
           mTempLabel2->SetText(score_msg3);
       }
   }
```

I want to save the value of 'score' integer only when count = 1, and display it when count = 2, the problem is the value of 'score' changes when count = 2 and so the value of score is different when count = 1, how might i save or caputure the value of 'score' when count = 1 and display it outside the If statement (or anywhere else) **before** it changes

Comment: `int saved_score = score`?

Comment: if i initialise saved_score = score inside if (count ==1), then how can i use this same saved_score variable inside if (count == 2) given the fact that when count = 2 the value of score has changed from when count was 1

Comment: Sorry, it has to have scope outside the function (because it has to persist between function calls) so it must be a member variable.